# Relative Risk Coefficient

Tags: r, python

I tried to find relative risk coefficient using both R and Python.

In R I used: `mod <- glm(vital_status ~ factor(Radiation_Therapy, levels=c(1,0)), family="poisson"(link="log"), data=data)`
and got `0.3317` as coefficient.

In Python I used : `mod = sm.GLM(endog, exog, family=sm.families.Poisson())`
[where exog, endog = sm.add_constant(x), y and x is the column of Radiation_therapy and y is the column of vital_status]
and got `-0.3317` as coefficient.

Why is there a negative sign in the coefficient which was found in python?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of
`factor(Radiation_Therapy, levels=c(1,0))`
which asks for the `1` level to be the first and the `0` level the second. The coefficient will then be the mean in the `0` level minus the mean in the `1` level.  As far as I can tell, you didn't ask for a reversal like that in the Python code